# How to create a list of index values based on 2 lists in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to work on an assignment, however am really stuck on this section. What I need to do is write a predicate called matching with three parameters, all lists. The third list must contain the index of the positions in which the first two lists contain the same value. I really don't know where to start on this so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you give an example of what the third list would contain? I would like to double check I understand this to avoid sending you in the wrong direction.

Comment: you can start looking at findall/3 and nth1/3 documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The third list must contain the index of the positions in which the first two lists contain the same value.

First important:

> The third list must contain the index of the positions in which the first two lists contain *the same value*.

Use unification. As predicate:

```
same_value(X, X).
```

> The third list must contain the index of the positions in which *the first two lists contain the same value*.

```
lists_same_value([X|_], [Y|_]) :- same_value(X, Y). % succeed
lists_same_value([_|Xs], [_|Ys]) :-                 % skip head
    lists_same_value(Xs, Ys).                       % recursive definition
```

Simplify and unify in head:

```
lists_same_value([X|_], [X|_]).     % succeed
lists_same_value([_|Xs], [_|Ys]) :- % skip head element
    lists_same_value(Xs, Ys).       % recursive definition
```

> The third list must contain the *index of the positions in which the first two lists contain the same value*.

Add accumulator for current index, succeed when heads are same element, and look in rest of list.

```
lists_same_value_index([X|_], [X|_], N, N).      % succeed
lists_same_value_index([_|Xs], [_|Ys], N0, N) :- % skip head element
    succ(N0, N1),                                % next index
    lists_same_value_index(Xs, Ys, N1, N).       % recursive definition
```

Instantiate accumulator:

```
lists_same_value_index(Xs, Ys, N) :-
    lists_same_value_index(Xs, Ys, 0, N).
```

Use it with `bagof` to find all solutions:

```
?- bagof(N, lists_same_value_index([a,b,c,a,c,d,c], [a,c,c,a,d,d,c], N), Ns).
Ns = [0, 2, 3, 5, 6].
```

---

and no this is not the same as the solution with the two `nth0` of course, see:

```
?- numlist(1, 100, L), time( bagof(N, lists_same_value_index(L, L, N), Ns) ).
% 314 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (98% CPU, 1785481 Lips)
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9|...],
Ns = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8|...].

?- numlist(1, 100000, L), time( bagof(N, lists_same_value_index(L, L, N), Ns) ).
% 300,014 inferences, 0.052 CPU in 0.052 seconds (100% CPU, 5765387 Lips)
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9|...],
Ns = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8|...].
```

and then with `nth0`:

```
?- numlist(1, 100, L), time( findall(N, ( nth0(N, L, E), nth0(N, L, E) ), Ns) ).
% 2,181 inferences, 0.001 CPU in 0.001 seconds (100% CPU, 3329847 Lips)
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9|...],
Ns = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8|...].

?- numlist(1, 100000, L), time( findall(N, ( nth0(N, L, E), nth0(N, L, E) ), Ns) ).
% 1,667,166,681 inferences, 151.139 CPU in 151.244 seconds (100% CPU, 11030703 Lips)
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9|...],
Ns = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8|...].
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Capellic suggested you can use findall/3 and nth1/3 predicates:

```
common_elemnts_pos(L1,L2,Pos):- 
           findall(X, (nth0(X,L1,Elem), nth0(X, L2, Elem)) , Pos).
```

The above simply says that find all positions X that the element in L1 is Elem and element in L2 is Elem, so the have same element.

Example:

```
?- common_elemnts_pos([1,3,4,5,7,9],[1,2,4,5,8,9],Pos).
Pos = [0, 2, 3, 5].
```

It is also easy to do a pure recursive solution like:

```
common_elemnts_pos(L1,L2,Pos):- common_elemnts_pos(L1,L2,Pos,0).

common_elemnts_pos([],_,[],_).
common_elemnts_pos(_,[],[],_).
common_elemnts_pos([H|T],[H|T1],[CurrentPos|T2],CurrentPos):- 
                               N_CurrentPos is CurrentPos+1,
                               common_elemnts_pos(T,T1,T2,N_CurrentPos).
common_elemnts_pos([H|T],[H1|T1],T2,CurrentPos):- 
                               dif(H,H1), N_CurrentPos is CurrentPos+1,
                               common_elemnts_pos(T,T1,T2,N_CurrentPos).
```

Example:

```
?- common_elemnts_pos([1,3,4,5,7,9],[1,2,4,5,8,9],Pos).
Pos = [0, 2, 3, 5] ;
Pos = [0, 2, 3, 5] ;
false.
?- common_elemnts_pos([1,3,4,5,7,9],[1,2,4,5,8,9],Pos).
Pos = [0, 2, 3, 5] ;
false.
```

In first test above there are two same solutions because both base cases are valid. If you want only one you could replace:

```
common_elemnts_pos([],_,[],_).
common_elemnts_pos(_,[],[],_).
```

with base case:

```
common_elemnts_pos([],[_|_],[],_).
common_elemnts_pos(_,[],[],_).
```