# Prolog - Comparing Lists that have the same element on the same index

Tags: prolog

I've been working on Prolog for a few weeks right now.  I am now trying to write a function in it called matching:

> Write a predicate called matching with three parameters, all lists. 
>   The third     list must contain the index of the positions in which
>   the first two lists contain the same value.

If I run

```
matching([10,71,83,9,24,5,2],[8,71,26,9],Positions).
```

The results are:

```
?- matching([10,71,83,9,24,5,2],[8,71,26,9],Positions).
Positions = [] ;
Positions = [] ;
Positions = [_2420] ;
Positions = [_2420] ;
Positions = [_2420, _2432];...
```

The correct answer would be that Positions is bound to `[1,3]`. I have no idea what is wrong with my code.  Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: See this question, it is the same question I think: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43313755/7473772

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hint? Each of your `matchingHelper` clauses contains a mistake!

---

OK, a little more than a hint:

**Base cases**

Prolog should be giving you a warning about singleton variables here. ListofIndex is a variable, but it is only used in one place. Essentially this means that there is absolutely no constraint on this, and thus can be anything.

The correct thing would be that if either of the input lists is empty, the output is also empty.

matchingHelper([], _, *, []).
matchingHelper(*, [], _, []).

**Equal case**

This one you almost have correct, but the way you deal with `ListOfIndex` is backwards. You construct a `NewListOfIndex` based on the predicate arguments, and use that in the recursive call. The problem is that the `ListOfIndex` is actually the output! So you should instead construct the `ListOfIndex` based on the output from the recursive call.

```
matchingHelper([X|Xs], [X|Ys], Index, [Index|ListofIndex]) :-
    Index2 is Index + 1,
    matchingHelper(Xs, Ys, Index2, ListofIndex).
```

**Unequal case**

Just 2 little issues with this one. First is that this clause should only apply if X and Y are different. Just using a different variable name does not enforce this. Because there is a previous clause which handles the equal case, the first result prolog finds would be correct, but it will continue to find other, incorrect solutions because of this.

The second issue is that you don't increment the index. If you ignore the first element, the current index has to be incremented to reflect the current position.

```
matchingHelper([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], Index, ListofIndex) :-
    X \= Y,
    Index2 is Index + 1,
    matchingHelper(Xs, Ys, Index2, ListofIndex).
```

---

Here's a sample run:

```
?- matching([10,71,83,9,24,5,2],[8,71,26,9],Positions).
Positions = [1, 3]
false
```

Comment: Thanks for much for this in-depth answer.  Sorry I can't think of anything to ask with a quick skim, I'll read it carefully, thank you.  Yes it does give me warnings on the singletons.  I also figured out the wrong thing with the base cases a few minutes ago but didn't get to edit my code here, haha.

Comment: those were indeed my problems, solved it, thank you.